# Doing String interpolation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I print the no:of comments to a particular post under it in rails?

```
<%=@post.comments.any? ? " " : "No comments yet!!" %>
```

This is what I have done. Instead, if there are any comments for a particular post, I want to display it like "There are 5 comments" or something.

pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the number of comments:

```
<%= @post.comments.any? ? "#{@post.comments.size} comments" : "No comments yet!!" %>
```

**NOTE 1:** You can also use Rails helper for printing pluralized strings using [`pluralize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize):

```
<%= @post.comments.any? ? pluralize(@post.comments.size, "comment") : "No comments yet!!" %>
```

**NOTE 2:** Also, use `.size` instead of `.count`. Because `size` will count number of elements in your collection, whereas `count` will hit the database and count the rows in the database.

Comment: I want to add a like facility for the posts. What to do?

Comment: Well, first you need to mark the answer "correct" if it has solved your problem. Then, upvote it as a "thank your". And only then, ask another question, since SO has a rule of "one post, one question".